# Simplify Matrices and Vector Multiplication

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I got following equation:

$\begin{bmatrix}
b_{u_1}\\
b_{u_2}\\
b_{u_3}\\
b_{u_4}\\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{k}^T-k_p\cdot\vec{c}^T&K_I
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
e
\end{bmatrix}+k_p\cdot w\right)$

where $\vec{k}^T = \begin{bmatrix}k_1 & k_2 & k_3\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{1x3}$

where $\vec{c}^T = \begin{bmatrix}c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{1x3}$

and $k_p,K_I,w$ are scalars.

I want to multiply, and order it in the next step..

My first step would be to multiply $\vec{b}$ into the Bracelet.

$\begin{bmatrix}
b_{u_1}\\
b_{u_2}\\
b_{u_3}\\
b_{u_4}\\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{k}^T-k_p\cdot\vec{c}^T&K_I
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
e
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{u_1}\\
b_{u_2}\\
b_{u_3}\\
b_{u_4}\\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\left(k_p\cdot w\right)$

Then: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
b_{u_1}\\
b_{u_2}\\
b_{u_3}\\
b_{u_4}\\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{k}^T-k_p & K_I\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{u_1}\cdot\vec{k}^T-k_p & b_{u_1}\cdot K_I \\
b_{u_2}\cdot\vec{k}^T-k_p & b_{u_2}\cdot K_I \\
b_{u_3}\cdot\vec{k}^T-k_p & b_{u_3}\cdot K_I \\
b_{u_4}\cdot\vec{k}^T-k_p & b_{u_4}\cdot K_I \\
\end{bmatrix}$

but after that i have no idea..

Comment: What do you mean MathJax won't work here? All of MathJax and a lot of $\LaTeX$ works just fine.

Comment: Maybe some temporarily issues. Ive tried to Tex the equation, but it only draw one row instead of 4 rows.

Comment: The stuff inside the big parentheses evaluates to a scalar quantity.
$$\lambda = (k_1x_1 + k_2x_2 + k_3x_3) - k_p(c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + c_3x_3) + K_1e + k_pw$$
So the entire expression is just a scalar multiple of the vector on the far LHS.